# Network Tab is missing in Openstack dashboard?

Tags: juju, openstack, cloud

I have successfully configured MAAS and JUJU and after that I have executed following commands;

```
juju deploy --to lxc:0 mysql;     
juju deploy --to lxc:0 keystone;      
juju deploy --to lxc:0 nova-cloud-controller;       
juju deploy --to lxc:0 glance; juju deploy --to lxc:0 rabbitmq-server;      
juju deploy --to lxc:0 openstack-dashboard;     
juju deploy --to lxc:0 cinder;      
juju deploy nova-compute;     

juju add-relation mysql keystone;        
juju add-relation nova-cloud-controller mysql;                  
juju add-relation nova-cloud-controller rabbitmq-server;            
juju add-relation nova-cloud-controller glance;             
juju add-relation nova-cloud-controller keystone;             
juju add-relation nova-compute nova-cloud-controller;                
juju add-relation nova-compute mysql;                   
juju add-relation nova-compute rabbitmq-server:amqp;               
juju add-relation nova-compute glance;               
juju add-relation glance mysql;                     
juju add-relation glance keystone;               
juju add-relation glance cinder;                        
juju add-relation mysql cinder;                        
juju add-relation cinder rabbitmq-server;                       
juju add-relation cinder nova-cloud-controller;                   
juju add-relation cinder keystone;                              
juju add-relation openstack-dashboard keystone;
```

After this I am able to login to horizon dashboard and successfully made few instances in the openstack dashboard.

However could not allocate floating ips to them.

All I can figure-out is that neutron gateway is missing. Can anybody guide me step by step how to deploy and configure NEUTRON gateway ?? and make the things working.

Also I am unable to see Network tab in Horizon Dashboard.